# Highcharts form submit var not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to populate my Highcharts graph by a form submit/click function.  For some reason I can't get the var to pass any value.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var gaA = $('#gaA').val();
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  chart.series[0].data[0].update(gaA);
  chart.series[0].data[1].update(50);
  chart.series[0].data[2].update(50);
});
```

If I change

```
var gaA = $('#gaA').val();
```

to

```
var gaA = 500;
```

it passes the value of 500.  But I need this to populate from the form.

Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/reLuP/1/

Comment: is #gaA a input type text element?

Comment: yes.

    <input type="text" id="gaA" value="" />

Comment: This should work then. to get an answer post your whole html and js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
var gaA = parseFloat($('#gaA').val());
```

To receive number format, which is used by highcharts, instead of text value.

Answer (score 2):

`val` returns a string, but you need a number.  Force it to a number with the unary plus operator or `parseFloat`

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(+gaA);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reLuP/2/)